# hundreds of session (sess_*) files in C:\wamp64\tmp directory starting 2023-12-02

Tags: windows, session, wamp64

On Windows I am running a php script on command line.

I set it to close and start again every 10 minutes.

Starting on 2023-12-02 0941h (GMT+8) it creates a blank sess_[some random characters] each time it starts.

I have already edited the php script to not use SESSION. However the session files are still being created in the C:\wamp64\tmp directory.

I have already edited the php script to not use SESSION. I expected the script to not create the session files anymore, but they are still being created.